# To convert address data in json to an address object

Tags: c#, json, web-services, visual-studio-2015

When making a request for an address web service, I get the following Json:

```
{
    "cep": "04194-280",
    "logradouro": "Rua Memorial de Aires",
    "complemento": "",
    "bairro": "Jardim São Savério",
    "localidade": "São Paulo",
    "uf": "SP",
    "unidade": "",
    "ibge": "3550308",
    "gia": "1004"
}
```

I need to convert this json to the following object:

```
    public class Endereco
    {
        [JsonProperty("cep")]
        public string CEP { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("logradouro")]
        public string Logradouro { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("complemento")]
        public string Complemento { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("bairro")]
        public string Bairro { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("localidade")]
        public string Localidade { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("uf")]
        public string UF { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("ibge")]
        public string IBGE { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("unidade")]
        public string Unidade { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("gia")]
        public string GIA { get; set; }
    }
```

The code that converts json to an object is as follows:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    string jsonAddress = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(client.DownloadString("http://viacep.com.br/ws/" + tboCep.Text + "/json/"));
    Addressa ddr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Endereco>(jsonAddress);

    tboCidade.Text = address.Localidade; //City
    tboEstado.Text = address.UF;         // State
    tboRua.Text = address.Logradouro;    // Street
    tboBairro.Text = address.Bairro;     // District
}
```

But I always get the following error:

```
Error converting value "{
  "cep": "04194-280",
  "logradouro": "Rua Memorial de Aires",
  "complemento": "",
  "bairro": "Jardim SÃ£o SavÃ©rio",
  "localidade": "SÃ£o Paulo",
  "uf": "SP",
  "unidade": "",
  "ibge": "3550308",
  "gia": "1004"
}" to type 'ApiCorreios.Endereco'. Path '', line 1, position 269.
```

Would anyone know how to solve or have a better suggestion? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You are double serializing. take the string returned directly from the web call and deseirlaize that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are **double** serializing here.

```
string jsonAddress = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(client.DownloadString("http://viacep.com.br/ws/" + tboCep.Text + "/json/"));
```

the string returned from the client is already a serialized object and you are basically serializing it again.

Take the string returned directly from the web call and deseirlaize that

```
string jsonAddress = client.DownloadString("http://viacep.com.br/ws/" + tboCep.Text + "/json/");
var ddr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Endereco>(jsonAddress);
```